# Google Play Service SignIn Failure ApiException 4

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games, google-play-console

So I followed the guide from https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling, to enable the google play service for your app. Instead of using the already existing debug.keystore. I created a new one with:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore debug.keystore -storepass android -alias androiddebugkey -keypass android -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

I added test users, I added the app id to my manifest and the google play console shows me a green light everywhere. However if I try to connect silently or via Button I get following error msg (I am using the code of one of their sample apps):

```
D/ButtonClicker2000: onResume()
D/ButtonClicker2000: signInSilently()
D/ButtonClicker2000: signInSilently(): failure
com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 4: 4: 
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb.zzy(Unknown Source:14)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbk.zzz(Unknown Source:0)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzbl.zzr(Unknown Source:32)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.zzc(Unknown Source:81)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzs.setResult(Unknown Source:41)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzg.zza(Unknown Source:24)
    at com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.zzt.onTransact(Unknown Source:53)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:752)
D/ButtonClicker2000: onDisconnected()
```

I tried searching for ApiException: 4: 4: but I didn't find anything helpful, neither am I using Firebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so my fault was that I either had an old Android Studio version (and the location for the keystore file was different then) or I specified a different location for my debug.jks at one point.

So yeah the Sha1 key was not from my actual project.
Fixed it by following these instructions:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing